# How to identify online users in through Webrtc API

Tags: javascript, webrtc, p2p

How to Identify Online users in WebRTC app?
Iam using  Sip signalling and Sip.js. Iam unable to find proper documentation or on web.
I thought to send invite request to all contacts and if one responds,that one is online,BUT for sending request back from client 2 we need to create peerconnection or data Channel, that wil be against Proper technique..so pls suggest me something 
Many begginers may be facing this problem so I thought this will teah me plus benefit others.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Comment: Identifying online users can be achieved using any suitable signalling channel(web sockets etc), however please remember that WebRTC does not provide or mandates any signalling protocol, so there's no out of the box support for online presence in WebRTC per say. Signalling part has been left to the users whatever they choose to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not obvious from your question if you use some SIP server along with sip.js.

1. If you do you can use built-in mechanisms: [Asterisk](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+13+Configuration_res_pjsip#Asterisk13Configuration_res_pjsip-contact_qualify_frequency) `qualify`, [Freeswitch Sofia](https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/Sofia+Configuration+Files#SofiaConfigurationFiles-all-reg-options-ping) `ping`, etc. Most of such mechanisms send SIP OPTIONS to client and consider any response as success.
2. In case of serverless setup you could use [SIP MESSAGE](https://sipjs.com/api/0.11.0/message/) to "ping" remote party.
   You shouldn't just send MESSAGE to all possible peers rather maintain the list of registered one (similar to SIP REGISTER approach in SIP server based applications).